# lock iList .net thread safe

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Im just confused why adding to a list would not be thread safe like below

```
object aLock = new object();
List<string> aList = new List<string>

lock(aLock)
   aList.Add("abc");
```

Not sure why a lock would be required where all you are doing is adding to it.
Why would such a scenario be not thread safe?

Comment: ...if two threads add at the same time....

Comment: Also, locking a different object from each thread (e.g. here `aLock` is a local, so two threads running this code would lock on a different instance each) is an expensive way to do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code is useless- as @Jon mentions, all threads would be locking on their own object, which means they wouldn't be blocking each other at all.  Might as well leave out the lock statement entirely.

First of all, you need to lock on an object that's common to all of the threads (like the list itself).  For instance:

```
lock (aList)
    aList.Add("abc");
```

As for "why", the internal implementation of the List may (does) perform actions that are not safe to perform in parallel on multiple threads.  This is documented in the [List class MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> A List can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to
>   ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

Comment: **Careful!** Locking on the list itself is also a bug unless the list's visibility is restricted to a known scope (e.g. if it is a `private` field). In general, access to the lock target **must** be constrained to a known scope -- which is impossible if the lock target is `public`.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand you explanation Jon, why is locking on the List an issue if it is public?

Comment: Because you lock on the instance (the contents) of the property, not the property itself. If it is public, then any other part of your code might come in and change the contents, resulting in some thread holding a lock on an object that is no longer what other threads are locking on.